# How to import ImageField from excel

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export, Excel file as file.xlsx

when importing  an ImageField the image is saved as a link  "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\images\gallery\29.jpg" and not an actual image into database.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField( max_length=200, verbose_name='Nom')
    slug         = models.SlugField( max_length=150, unique= True, verbose_name='URL')
    reference    = models.CharField( max_length=200, verbose_name='Référence', unique=True, 
                    blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PhotoProduct(models.Model):

    image     = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/produits') 
    actif     = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='actif', default=True)
    product   = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="photos", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)
```

###########

ressources.py

```
class PhotoProductAdminResource(resources.ModelResource):
    product   = fields.Field(column_name='product', attribute='product', 
                       widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Product, field='id'))
    class Meta:
        model = PhotoProduct
        fields = ( 
            'id',
            'product',
            'actif',
            'image',
        )
```

###########

admin.py

```
@admin.register(PhotoProduct)
class PhotoProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'product', 'actif')
    list_display_links = ('id','product', )
    list_editable = [ 'actif']
    resource_class = PhotoProductAdminResource 
    form = PhotoProductModelForm
```

Comment: The answer in [this issue](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/90#issuecomment-729731655) may help

Comment: that did not work.

Answer (score -1):

In the model `PhotoProduct`, any saved instance with an image will have its relative path (starting from `upload_to` parameter) saved in the Database. an example could be **"images/produits/patate.png"**.

Here is the working trick for images that are all stored in a folder.

1. if all your product images are all stored in `"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\images"`, you could just copy that folder and paste it into your django `STATIC_ROOT/images/produits`
2. import all your `PhotoProduct` xlsx sheet with image link as mentioned above.